Find/Set Azure Functions Core Tools version Visual Studio use
Got below error while trying to run the Azure Function in VS2022 locally.
This version of the Azure Functions Core Tools requires your project to reference version 4.5.0 or later of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions. 

It can be fixed by updating the version of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions, however that's also mean I will need to spend quite some times to test as code coverage is not good enough.
As a short term solution, would like to know how can I find out the Azure Functions Core Tools version VS is using, as well as how to rollback to the pervious version?

Open View=>Terminal in Visual Studio, run func --version command to get the version of function core tools. Refer Image

Got a error func : The term 'func' is not recognized any idea? And will you happen also know how I can use a difference version?

You have to install function core tools using the command npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true. You can run this command in command prompt. or you can directly install using MSI, refer MSDOC

Are you sure you are checking the 'func' command on command line and not powershell?

@Bill, check if below answers helps to fix the issue.

This error appeared with visual studio 2022 v17.12.0
after this update VS installed and forcing the Azure Functions Tools v4.0.6517 by default and based on Microsoft documentations

So we have to solution to solve this issue, the first one is to Update Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions nuget package to be 4.5.0 and this will solve the issue,
but what if you don't want to update this package at all, then you will need to downgrade the version of Azure Core Tools, so the following steps explains how to do it

Close the VS
Do manual installation for Core Tools v4.0.6280 (older version)
Copy the content of folder --> C:\ProgramFiles\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools
Paste it to --> C:\Users\{your username}\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.104.0\cli_x64
Restart your PC or Laptop
Open the VS again and try to run any azure function, you will notice that the console is now showing the older version of the Core Tools.


I hope this answer may help someone.

Thanks, this is by far the simplest to me. One quick notes, folder to replace at point (4) depends on the latest VS installed and the MSI on point (2) can be found here

In order to fix the error showed in @Bill question, I run the followed steps:

In Nuget Package Manager: update Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions to 4.5.0 version
In Visual Studio 2022: Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Azure Functions -> Check for updates
After Check for updates, click in Download & Install button


Thanks, unfortunately I am looking for a workaround to not update Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions

Incase your functions are running in isolated worker model, you need to update the same on local.settings.json file for running your functions locally from visual studio as following.
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",

I was also getting the same error, which got resolved after updating the runtime

This fixed it for me


find out the Azure Functions Core Tools version VS is using

You can find out the function core tool version using the command func --version.
Navigate to View=>Terminal in Visual Studio, run func --version command as below:

You can check the function core tools version in .csproj of your project:
   <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>

Generally, Visual studio picks up the recently installed version of Azure function core tools.
As mentioned in MSDOC, If you have 4.0.6517 (or) later versions of the Function Core Tools, in-process model function projects must reference 4.5.0 or later versions of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.
In case if you use earlier versions the package Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Function, the function execution will throw the error.
Follow below steps to roll back the core tools version:

If you used an MSI on Windows to install core tools, uninstall the current one and install the latest MSI, refer the document to install different versions of Core Tools on Windows.



If you used npm command, use below commands:

npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@3 --unsafe-perm true.


Hey Pravallika, I have tried to install a older version with npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4.0.6280 however VS seems still try to use the once it installed under \AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\4.100.0-inprocess

Delete the AzureFunctionsTools folder and restart Visual Studio.

Tested VS will throw a error then download the latest and use =[

Which folder did you delete, AzureFunctionCoreTools or AzureFunctionTools folder?

It it the folder \AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\

I mysteriously started receiving this error in my project after having run it many times, and I was still able to run a different Azure Functions project without issues. It turned out the culprit was a --csharp argument that was added to commandLineArgs in launchSettings.json (this is also accessible through the UI via the Solution Explorer project's Properties > Debug > General > Open Debug Launch Profiles UI). Removing this argument corrected the issue.
I've found almost no information on this --csharp argument. It's not listed as an argument to func.exe, but it is, evidently, In-Process-specific and causes that error in my project which is using the Isolated worker model ("FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated" in local.settings.json).
From this github issue, I can see that in the referenced older version of the Azure Function Core Tools (3.0.2534), in response to certain scenarios, it used to give a warning saying,

Can't determine project language from files. Please use one of
[--csharp, --javascript, --typescript, --java, --python,
--powershell])

in response to some other configuration issues. I'm guessing this is why someone added it to my project. What's strange is I'm pretty sure I've run the project successfully many times since it was added so I suspect an update to Func.exe changed how the argument is handled resulting in this error (it's now running 4.0.6543).

This fixed it for me

Fix for Rider
Install Azure Functions Core Tool:
npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true

This version work for me: 4.0.6280 should be less than 4.0.6517
func --version

Fix Rider:
Settings -> Tools -> Azure -> Functions -> v4 = From environment PATH

Work around
I'm having the same issue in Rider but I found that you can still run the functions from the terminal or in my case from Visual Studio:
func host start --pause-on-error --port 1337

As a Rider user, I want to add that I tried everything above, and no solutions worked for me.
What I needed to do was download the latest experimental release of Rider, and then it "magically worked". No code change. Anybody reading this and desperate may try the same or use the 30 day trial.

To fix this issue, I have added below 2 lines in my local.settings.json file
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
"FUNCTIONS_V2_COMPATIBILITY_MODE": true,


For those still running in-process model, you also need to specify
"FUNCTIONS_INPROC_NET8_ENABLED": 1
and
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
in your local.setting.json. From this MS docs section that I finally stumbled across.
This was the only thing that worked for me, even after specifying that variable in my environment and restarting VS! Hope this helps somebody.
Sample local.settings.json:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_INPROC_NET8_ENABLED": "1",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    }
}

